# can't control color of menu element in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8Sd9m/ (Open the 'result' window wide enough to get the desktop menubar, not the collapsed smartphone menu.)

I'm trying to customize a Twitter Bootstrap site with new colors and styles. Without a LESS install, I'm doing it with good old-fashioned CSS overrides.

The problem I'm having right now is with the menu items. I can override the default grey background with red, but if I click on "Our Team" or "Portfolio" to open a dropdown, then mouse down to the dropdown, the menu item switches to default gray.

The weird part is, if I select the `<a>` tag in question in my Chrome or Firefox debugger, it switches back to red! It's only before selecting the tag in my debugger that is has a gray background.

I think this must be some feature of the Bootstrap Dropdown JS, but I can't see it changing anything in the DOM, either styles or classes.

---

Essential CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #eb212e;
    border-color: #eb212e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #eb212e;
    background-color: #eb212e;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to change:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #E7E7E7; /* change to your own color */
    color: #555555;/* change to your own color */
}
```

Specifically `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your css: The `:focus` state for the `a` tag

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.open > a:focus {
    background-color: #eb212e;
}
```

Your fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/8Sd9m/5/**